# On Hybrid Runbook Worker suddenly all jobs are getting suspended

Tags: azure-automation

I have an automation account configured with a Hybrid Runbook Worker, suddenly all jobs are getting suspended with the error:

Job was suspended. For additional troubleshooting, check the Microsoft-SMA event logs on the computers in the Hybrid Runbook Worker Group that tried to run this job.

Any idea? what can be the issue

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed, it was a brief issue with the service.